# Where can I download the jar file for the datasync API?

Tags: java-me, synchronization, data-synchronization, jsr, syncml

I want to use `javax.microedition.datasync` in my MIDlet application to synchronize data of my mobile phone with a computer. The problem is that I don't know where to find the library used by the `JSR-230`. So if someone knows where to get the library of this jsr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this isn't downloadable, because the status of this JSR is [inactive](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=230), that is mean:

[...the JSR has not gone final and that its Spec Lead and Expert Group have not published a milestone draft for their JSR in more than 18 months...](http://www.jcp.org/en/introduction/faq4#12)